# Sprout SEO 3 Image Override Not Working

Tags: plugin-sproutseo

So I have what *seems* like a simple problem but can't quite find a solution. On my entry template I'm trying to override the image fields as we're using the imager plugin for transforms. However, it doesn't seem to be working at all. No matter what I put inside the `craft.sproutSeo.meta` do loop, nothing happens. Even if I hardcode a value in there. It seems simple, but is there something I'm missing here? My code is below:

```
{% set cardEntryImage = craft.imager.transformImage(entry.blogHeaderImage.first(), { width: 1920, ratio: 16/9 }) %}
{% do craft.sproutSeo.meta({
    ogImage: siteUrl ~ cardEntryImage.getUrl(),
    ogImageSecure: siteUrl ~ cardEntryImage.getUrl(),
    ogImageHeight: cardEntryImage.getHeight(),
    ogImageWidth: cardEntryImage.getWidth(),
    ogImageType: cardEntryImage.getMimeType(),
    twitterImage: siteUrl ~ cardEntryImage.getUrl()
}) %}
```

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem so this is not an answer but more a bump, sorry for that. Based on this page at their docs ([link](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/seo/docs/advanced-customization/template-overrides)), the method described above should work... But for me it isn't. I've contacted the Sprout support as well, will post back here if I get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please let us know where do you output the `{% sproutseo 'optimize' %}`tag?

The `{% do craft.sproutSeo.meta({` tag need to be called before the `optimize` tag. I'll give you a basic example of how you can do this:

Let's say that you have a `_layout` where you have the html `head` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
    {% block head %}
        {% sproutseo 'optimize' %}
        ...
        ...
    {% endblock %}
    ...
</head>
```

In your `section/_entry` (extends your layout) When you need to override something with the `do craft.sproutSeo.meta` you may need to call it before the `{% sproutseo 'optimize' %}` so you can do something like:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}
{% set title = entry.title ~ " - Blog" %}

{% block head %}

    {% set cardEntryImage = craft.imager.transformImage(entry.blogHeaderImage.first(), { width: 1920, ratio: 16/9 }) %}
    {% do craft.sproutSeo.meta({
        ogImage: siteUrl ~ cardEntryImage.getUrl(),
        ogImageSecure: siteUrl ~ cardEntryImage.getUrl(),
        ogImageHeight: cardEntryImage.getHeight(),
        ogImageWidth: cardEntryImage.getWidth(),
        ogImageType: cardEntryImage.getMimeType(),
        twitterImage: siteUrl ~ cardEntryImage.getUrl()
    }) %}
    {{ parent() }}

    ...
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

Best,

-Andre L

Comment: That works! thanks! I had the call to optimize before doing the overrides, as indicated in the (wrong at the time but now fixed) documentation